# FastAPI: How to get JSON file from request & save it

Tags: python, json, fastapi

```
@router.get("/products", tags=["Product"], response_model=list[schemas.Product])
def get_all_product(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return get_products(db)

def get_products(db: Session):
    products = db.query(models.Product).all()
    return products
```

The above works fine, when I go to localhost:5000/products I get a JSON file.

I want to save that JSON file on my computer, but the following code returns an error:

```
def get_all_product(db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    with open('save_products.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8' ) as fp:
        json.dump(get_products(db), fp)
    return get_products(db)
```

> TypeError: Object of type Product is not JSON serializable.

I understand I have to make my 'Product' class serializable, but it seems FastAPI can already do that by itself (otherwise I wouldn't get a JSON file already through my request).

Comment: `get_products(db)` probably returns a set of SQLAlchemy objects? (since you didn't include that part of your code, it's hard for anyone else to say which type they are); FastAPI converts this through Pydantic (when `from_orm` is configured on the model). You can do the same conversion with `products = parse_obj_as(List[schemas.Product], get_products(db))` - you can then convert these to a dict an serialize them: `json.dump([product.dict() for product in products])`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a list of SQLAlchemy objects to their Pydantic representations (which is what FastAPI does internally when you return them), you can use the utility function `parse_obj_as` from Pydantic.

```
products = parse_obj_as(List[schemas.Product], get_products(db))
```

`products` will now be a list of Pydantic Product objects instead of SQLAlchemy, and these objects can be converted to a dict through Pydantics regular serialization support:

```
list_of_product_dicts = [product.dict() for product in products])
```

You can then serialize this list by using `json.dump`:

```
json.dump(list_of_product_dicts)
```

Comment: This is a good start, but depending on the data types in `schemas.Product`, its `.dict()` might not be JSON serializable (e.g. if it contains a `datetime` object). In that case, you could use `from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder; list_of_product_dicts = jsonable_encoder(products)`.